# How can I make this code shorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to improve my coding skills and started to learn jquery. I started from simple things like making a very simple image showcase. Here is the code I've written so far. But it seems too long and not very efficient. Is there any way I can improve this?

Html:

```
<div id="galerija">
  <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid red; width: 600px; height: 450px;background-image: url(images/gora_big_main.png);" class="big_image"></div>
  <div style="float:left;"id="trumbai">

  <div style="border: 1px solid red; cursor: pointer; width: 150px; height: 75px; background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_1.png);"class="trumb_1"></div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; cursor: pointer; width: 150px; height: 75px; background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_2.png);"class="trumb_2"></div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; cursor: pointer; width: 150px; height: 75px; background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_2.png);"class="trumb_3"></div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; cursor: pointer; width: 150px; height: 75px; background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_main.png);"class="main_trumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".trumb_1").click(function(){
      $(".big_image").css("background-image","url('images/gora_big_1.png')");
    });
  });
  $(function(){
    $(".trumb_2").click(function(){
      $(".big_image").css("background-image","url('images/gora_big_2.png')");
    });
  });
  $(function(){
    $(".trumb_3").click(function(){
      $(".big_image").css("background-image","url('images/gora_big_3.png')");
    });
  });
  $(function(){
    $(".main_trumb").click(function(){
      $(".big_image").css("background-image","url('images/gora_big_main.png')");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to: 1. Avoid inline styles 2. Use actual images or `<img>` tags instead of background images 3. Use event delegation with `.on()`

Comment: Additionally, it might be better to have classes and ID's at the beginning of your element, followed by attributes. Like so: `<div id="test" class="container" style="" />`

Comment: This question might have a more suitable forum at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your styling into a linked css file so you don't have so much duplicate styling in the HTML:

HTML:

```
<div id="galerija">
   <div id="big_image"></div>
   <div id="trumbai">

      <div id="t1" "class="trumb"></div>
      <div id="t2" "class="trumb"></div>
      <div id="t3" "class="trumb"></div>
      <div id="tmain" "class="trumb"></div>

   </div>
</div>
```

A good rule of thumb is if you can find "style=" in your HTML, you have too much inline styling.

CSS:

```
#big_image
{
float: left;
border: 1px solid red;
width: 600px; height:
450px;background-image: url(images/gora_big_main.png);
}

#t1 {background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_1.png);}
#t2 {background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_2.png);}
#t3 {background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_3.png);}
#tmain {background-image: url(images/gora_trumb_main.png);}
#trumbai {float:left;}

.trumb //<--- notice how ALL of the styling for all class="trumb" is set in one place!
{
border: 1px solid red;
cursor: pointer;
width: 150px;
height: 75px;
}
```

Make use of variables in JavaScript:

```
imageClick("#t1", "gora_big_1")
imageClick("#t2", "gora_big_2")
imageClick("#t3", "gora_big_3")
imageClick("#tmain", "gora_big_main")

 function imageClick(id, imageName)
{
       $(function(){
            $("").click(function(){
                $(id).css("background-image","url('images/' + imageName + '.png')");
            });
        });
}
```

Notice I made imageClick() a very generic function so that it can be repeatedly used elsewhere. I call functions with ids as parameters, and keep ids out of the functions entirely. One block of code can then be recycled endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$(function() {
    $('#trumbai div').click(function() {
        $('.big_image').css('background-image', 'url('+ $(this).data('image') +')');
    });
});
```

Where your divs to be clicked on have the data attribute `image` containing the URL to the expanded image like so.

```
<div data-image="image/gora.png"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like the background image's URL changes as well.

Comment: Noticed that after posting - updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute to your div's for the big image and give a common class to all

```
<div data-big-image="images/gora_big_1.png" class="trumb" style...></div>
```

Then use the data attribute in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
        $(".trumb").on('click', function(){
            var bigImage = $(this).data('big-image');
            $(".big_image").css("background-image","url('" + bigImage + "')");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following to shorten your code:

```
$('[class^="trumb_"]').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var i = $(this).index();
        i += 1;
        var imgUrl = "images/gora_big_" + i + ".png";
        $(".big_image").css("background-image","url('" + imgUrl + "')");
    })
});

$(".main_trumb").click(function(){
    $(".big_image").css("background-image","url('images/gora_big_main.png')");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/255Qv/